# When will the "edit skin" in DNN 7.2 be used?

Tags: dotnetnuke, skin

I thought that the "edit skin" is a special skin that DNN will use when in page edit mode, but I tried and cannot make DNN load that skin. It will always use the default site skin or the individual page skin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would typically be used if you had the POPUPS disabled in the ADMIN setting, and a module loaded a secondary VIEW or EDIT control using the ControlKey parameters.

```
/PageName/ctl/View2/
```

As a module developer you would do this by having multiple controls defined in a module definition.

It could also be used even if you have Popups enabled, for controls that are marked to not support popups (defined in the module's definition).

Comment: So it is module dependent and cannot be used by default for a page, that requires an alternative skin for editing? Because that is what I tried to do, I have a page that distorts the top admin nav bar and thought I could easily circumvent this by specifying an edit skin that does not have this issue.

Comment: Pretty much for module development, depending on the module. You can choose that skin on a specific page, if you want, but that doesn't have anything to do with the EDIT skin setting, that would just be a Page Setting.